# How to update last row with the time now using C# & SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

My problem is when I update my database record with the time now the time is stopped in specific value and doesn't change.

This is my code

```
conn.Open();

SqlCommand sq = new SqlCommand("update Hodor_data set leaving_time = ('" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "') where mil_no = '" +textBox1.Text+ "' and times = (select max(times) from Hodor_data )", conn);

sq.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

and I tried to change the time by add timer refreshed the datetimepicker every one second but nothing changes and this is my result

[image: img]

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: what error it throwing

Comment: Beside of that even bigger problem @marc_s noticed, your `SqlCommand` is horribly to read this way.

Comment: what value dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() have

Comment: i know about sql injection but it's a software for home and don't connected with internet .. lock at time in the last record it is the same ,, i should close the program and run it again to refresh the time what i should do ?

Comment: What kind of `time` are you talking about???

Comment: @c4u why my sql command is horribly to read ?

Comment: @c4u simply i want to pick the time and update this record but it update the record with a stop time i want to refresh datetimepicker every second

Comment: @amrkamal Update to what? Current time?

Comment: Wait. If you want to `update the datetimepicker on EVERY second` why do you even use a `DateTimePicker`? Its a control to `pick` a `DateTime`. You'll be unable to pick anything when it updates on itself on every second.

Comment: ok so what i should do to update the record when i clicked the button every time with the current time ?

Comment: Even if this is *just for home* - just make it your habit **do NOT code like that!** Otherwise, out of habit, you'll end up having all those SQL injection holes in your code everywhere - even in the one that's *not only for home* ....

Comment: Yeah @marc_s I would like to sign your statement 100 times! Sloppy coding is a real bad habit. Using parameters in .net is that easy, so please let's use them!

Comment: i know u r right but now can u help me in the other problem ?

Comment: thx i will put your notice in my mind

Answer (score 1):

Let me clear a few things. You are doing *so* many things wrong..

First, you have a [bad habits to kick as choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) for your data. I saw `AM` and `PM` time designators in your `leaving_time` and `arrival_time` columns. That means they are character typed columns.

### Stop that!

If you save `DateTime` values to your database, insert them *directly* to your database to [`datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) or preferable [`datetime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) typed columns. Do **not** insert them as a `string` using like `ToString` method.

Second, you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. *Even* if it's a home project, **parameterized queries are always is the best way to do it**.

Third, use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods anually.

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var sq = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   sq.CommandText = @"update Hodor_data 
                      set leaving_time = @leaving
                      where mil_no = @milno 
                      and times = (select max(times) from Hodor_data )";

   sq.Parameters.Add("@leaving", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
   sq.Parameters.Add("@milno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

   conn.Open();
   sq.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```